# gvim line wrap should end current string and start a new one on next line

Tags: c++, editor, word-wrap, vim

I have the following line in my .gvimrc file to auto line wrap at 80 characters.

```
set textwidth=80
```

I also have the following lines to control the C++ code indentation.

```
set smartindent
set cindent
```

This works well most of the time, but has a limitation when typing long strings. The spaces or tabs added by the auto-indentation become a part of the string. For example, the line wrap currently does:

```
puts("I have put `set textwidth=80` in my `.gvimrc` file to make gvim
        automatically wrap long strings like this one.");
```

whereas I would like it to do the following:

```
puts("I have put `set textwidth=80` in my `.gvimrc` file to make gvim "
        "automatically wrap long strings like this one.");
```

This would ensure there are no spurious looking spaces in the output, while maintaining consistent code indentation.

Is there any way to configure gvim to do this? I have searched on the internet and on StackOverflow, but could not figure out how/if this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in `'formatoptions'` setting for that (yet), I'm afraid. However, formatting with `gq` and breaking of text beyond `'textwidth'` can be customized with a custom `'formatexpr'`, though I've seen that rarely used so far.

In case you don't want to attempt such an implementation, a simple workaround is setting `'colorcolumn'`; that visual aid will help you remembering to close the string and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before the text width is reached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like the `colorcolumn` workaround you suggested. I will give that a try.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/reformatting.html).

You can use the formatoption command to somewhat solve your problem